# MyFirstApp.java:7: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java

OK! I'm off to a flying STOP in my first java lesson. LOL

I'm getting this error:

```
# javac MyFirstApp.java
MyFirstApp.java:7: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
1 error
```

From the below code.

```
public class MyFirstApp {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println("I Rule!");
       System.out.println("The World");
      }
    }
}
```

And I'm pretty certain that I copied the example from the book exactly the way it was written. So where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You have on ´}` to much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation error exactly tells you where to look. MyFirstApp.java:7 implies there is something wrong at line 7. If you go through your code at line 7 there is an extra closing bracket. Remove this bracket and it would start compiling perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra closing brace `}`..

Try this..

```
public class MyFirstApp {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println("I Rule!");
       System.out.println("The World");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an unpaired `}` in your code.

```
public class MyFirstApp {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println("I Rule!");
       System.out.println("The World");
      }
    }
} // <-- Does not have a corresponding '{'
```